# Pandas DataFrame: Replace based on filter and regex extract

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, cjk

Here's a section of my dataframe:

```
   Type      Date        Diff   Data
0  Section   20171204    1.0    ~
1  Korean    20171204    1.0    저는 유양이에요.
2  English   20171204    1.0    Im Yooyang.
3  Theme     20171204    1.0    {"zh":"介绍","vi":"giới thiệu","ko":"소개","en":"I...
```

There are over 10,000 rows, ~500 of which are Type 'Theme'.

I'm trying to replace the Theme Data with only the Korean, i.e. `{"zh":"介绍","vi":"giới thiệu","ko":"소개","en":"I...` becomes `소개`.

I can extract the Korean-only text using regex `([가-힣]+)`.

I tried making a new df of just the new Theme Data, using
`df[df['Type'] == 'Theme'][['Data']].T.squeeze().str.extract('([가-힣]+)')`, but I can't figure out how to merge this back into the original df (`df[df['Type'] == 'Theme'][['Data']] =` doesn't work.

I tried replace, but I can't seem to do it just for Theme Data.

And apparently I shouldn't use an iterator: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: Wouldn't the Korean text vary across rows?

Comment: You could just load the Theme Data string as JSON using `json.loads` and just grab the `ko` value. Plus, as @CinCout said, there may potentially be other values than what you're trying to regex search on.

Comment: @CinCout The regex catches them all; it's the equivalent of [a-z]. I've checked :)

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Good idea, although how do I replace them that way? And would I have to loop through the entire df?

Comment: @Jamesdeluk you would have to use the `apply` or `map` function on the entire dataset. When I get home later, I'll write a possible solution.

Comment: @Jamesdeluk Ash Ketchum challenges your regex to a duel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `map` method together with an anonymous helper function, converting the string to a dict with `json.loads` and indexing via `loc`:

```py
import json

df.loc[df.Type == 'Theme', 'Data'] = df.loc[df.Type == 'Theme', 'Data'].map(lambda x: json.loads(x)["ko"])
```

Comment: Ah, excellent, thanks! Note for anyone with a similar need, I did have to make a separate named try/except function as not all values were in the json format. But yes, job done :)